# Cannot login using old user after new ubuntu upgrade

Tags: upgrade, 18.10, 19.04

Recently I upgraded from my old Ubuntu 18.10 to new Ubuntu 19.04 using the command

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

After the upgrade process is over(I think there was an error since the terminal doesn't asked me to reboot or anything)

But everything other than that went smooth.

After restart my system I was welcomed with gnome-setup window and they asked me to setup a user.

Which i did (my mistake).

After that i was logged into a fresh Ubuntu page and my old files were under another user under `/home` directory.

Now I cannot go back to the old user.
I tried switch user accounts but welcomed with the gnome-initial-setup window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by myself.
It is regarding the login session.

changing the session from gdm to lightdm solved my issue.

I don't know why that is an issue because upgrade from 18.04 to 18.10 was done by the same session and no issues was found, but 19.04 quacked an error.

`sudo dpkg-configure lightdm`

is the command you need to configure the same

Answer (score 0):

As long as the older `/home/old-username` exists, you should be able to recover the account.

Don't try to create a user, that has the same name as the home backup. Create a new one:

```
# create the new user
$ sudo adduser newuser

# add new user to sudo group
$ sudo adduser newuser sudo

# copy content of the old home to the new user
$ sudo cp -rT /home/old-username /home/newuser

# fix the permissions
$ sudo chown -R newuser:newuser /home/newuser/
```

Than login with new `newuser` and all your old data and configuration should be there.

Comment: but the problem is on my next boot i wont be able to use the new user but greeted with the gnome setup window